# (Matlab) Option to turn pause on and off from output callback of system(string)?

Tags: matlab

For an aerospace course aerelasticity I am doing an assignment with Nastran in Matlab (by using system(command) and bdf as input file).

I have attached a piece of my code as explanation. In this case the program Nastran produces a punch file (text) with displacements.

Currently the problem is that Matlab disregards the time Nastran needs for analysis to produce this punch file and continues on with the loop, however this punch file is not created yet so matlab turns out an error saying it does not exist and stops the loop.

I "have" a workaround for this by setting the pause times manually found from running it manually for increasing mesh sizes, this gives me at least some data on mesh convergence, however this is not a suitable method to use the rest of the assignment as it will take way too much time, therefore it must be automated.

I was thinking of setting a condition temporarily pausing the loop if the punch file does not exist and turning on again if it exists, however I got stuck with using a pause condition inside a while loop alltogether, it does not seem a solution to me.

Do you have any suggestions / ideas on what I could use / do how to get around this problem 
or 
know if there is a way to sent a callback from system(nastran) which i can use to create a condition to control the loop or something in that direction?

The following is a piece of code of the created function which turns out the Residual Mean squared error of the mesh which I use to see if the mesh converges:

```
%% Run Nastran
system('"C:\Users\$$$$\AppData\Roaming\MSC.Software\MSC_Nastran_Student_Edition\2014\Nastran\bin\nastranw.exe" nastranfile.bdf mem=1gb'); % Run the created bdf file 
pause(15);

%% Read results and save all relevant results

fpc = fopen('nastranfile.pch','r')

line = 0;
for j=1:6;
    line = line+1;
    fgets(fpc);
end 
line;
counter=0;
data = [];
while ~feof(fpc)
    counter= counter+1;
    str = fgets(fpc);
    line=line+1;
    str = str(61:73);
    data(counter) = str2num(str)
    fgets(fpc);
    line=line+1;
end 
line;
fclose(fpc);

% Find RMSE
mdl = fitlm(1:length(data),data);
RMEA = mdl.Rsquared.Adjusted;
RMSE = mdl.RMSE;
```